# Wicked PDF not rendering footer when PDF is created in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using the wicked PDF gem to generate PDFs for my application. I have had some logic in my controller which has been generating PDFs with footers and page numbers for some time.

I need to now generate this PDF in my model and since moving the controller render pdf code to the model, it hasn't been rendering a footer or proper margin.

This is the code in my controller which works:

```
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render  :pdf => "#{@user.id}_#{@paper.data["statementDate"]}",
            :template => "statements/monthly_statement_templates/#{@paper_template}",
            :footer => { :html => { template: 'statements/monthly_statement_templates/footer.pdf.erb' }},
            :title => "#{@paper.data["statementDate"]} Statement",
            :locals => { :statement => @paper.data },
            :margin => {
              :bottom => 20,
              :top => 20
            }
```

I've moved the code to the model. It looks like the following:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new()
av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths

# Need these in case the view constructs any links or references any helper methods.
av.class_eval do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ApplicationHelper
end

statement_pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      av.render :pdf => "#{statement.id}",
        :template => "statements/monthly_statement_templates/#{statement_template}",
        :footer => { :html => { :template => 'statements/monthly_statement_templates/shared/footer.pdf.erb' }},
        :locals => { :statement => statement.data },
        :margin => { :bottom => 20, :top => 20 }
    )
```

When comparing the two PDFs all of the data and styles within the template are the same. However, when rendering the PDF from the model it is not including the footer which has some text and page numbers.

My footer is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
    <style type="text/css">
      .legal { font-size: 8px; }
    </style>
    <script>
      function number_pages() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="number_pages()">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-xs-9 legal">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right legal">
            <small>Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```